# jQuery UI slider - Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I had this old jQuery UI slider that had worked just fine a few months ago, but now I seem to be getting an exception reading: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined. I've checked the values being passed into the slider and they're regular Javascript dates.

```
  $('#dateFilter').click(function() {
    return $('#sliderContainer').slideToggle(200);
  });

  $(function() {
    var endFiling, startFiling;
    startFiling = Date.parse($('#startFiling').val());
    endFiling = Date.parse($('#endFiling').val());
    return $('#filingDateSlider').slider({
      range: true,
      min: startFiling,
      max: endFiling,
      step: 86400000,
      values: [startFiling, endFiling],
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        var eD, end, sD, start;
        sD = new Date(ui.values[0]);
        start = dateFormat(sD);
        eD = new Date(ui.values[1]);
        end = dateFormat(eD);
        $('#filingStartDate').text(start);
        return $('#filingEndDate').text(end);
      }
        });
```

Is there a particular reason why I might be getting this new error?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp8vd.jpg

Comment: Are you able to set a breakpoint and walk through the code? The error sounds like to me that "addClass" is being called somewhere and the value being passed to it is undefined. If you can step through the code, perhaps you can see if the values are being initialized correctly. Also, have you changed the version of jQuery recently?

Comment: Did you check the log? jQuery UI has some bugs, the other day, I experienced a tiresome bug in a particular implementation of datepicker, it doesn't work if there is a text input in the same page!

Comment: I assume that "Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined." is coming from your jquery.js file?

Comment: @NickBeranek Yes, it's coming from the jQuery UI js file I've been using linked from Google's CDN.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For anyone reading back on this question, if you're pulling from a CDN, try pulling from the latest jQuery UI version. I also got this problem, and it was solved by using a later jQuery UI version.

Comment: I had the same problem with a scroll plugin and I pulled version 1.8.23 to my project and it is working like a charm now!

Comment: Success! Glad I could save someone some time. :-)

Comment: I wish I could "up" this answer with a million. Thanks!

Comment: I had to update jQueryUI from 1.8.17 to 1.9.2 and now it's working again. Thanks.

Comment: Since I was experiencing this bug with the newest stable release of jQueryUI (1.10.3), I used a hack get-around: by programatically setting the value of the slider (to whatever its initial value should be, zero for me) before anything else happens, it worked just fine...the "value: 0" in the slider initialization just wasn't taking for some reason.

Answer (score 22):

I solved this error by using integers in "min", "max" and "values". Maybe you are setting null values.

The jQuery Slider specification says:

> - max Number Default:100
> - min Number Default:0
> - value Number Default: 0

So "values" are an array of numbers.

Comment: ditto. I had `value` being set to an undefined variable.

Comment: I was grabbing my min/max etc from inputs using `.val()`, I had to wrap them in `parseInt()` and that sorted it for me

Comment: In my case I was setting max to NaN.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It happened to me when trying to set the value from an invalid input containing something else than an integer, so this is definitely linked.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who's still having this issue, ensure that the values you're adding (`min`, `max`, and `values` are all NUMBERS and not STRINGS!

Been trying to diagnose a problem where the following code was failing:

```
t.slider({
  range : true,
  min   : t.attr('data-min'),
  max   : t.attr('data-max'),
  values: [t.attr('data-min'), t.attr('data-max')],
  step  : 1.00,
  slide : function (e, ui) {
    var
      v = (s == 'price') ? '&pound;' + ui.values[0] + ' - &pound;' + ui.values[1] : ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1] + 'kg'
    $('#filter-' + s).html(v)
  },
  stop  : function () {
    Items.filter()
  }
})
```

As `t.attr()` returns a STRING, Slider was failing to set `valueMouse` on line 12843 of Version 1.10.1 of jQuery UI. Instead of being a value, it was returning a string (something similar to `39.99549.21` (min value of `39.99` concatenated with `549.21` - a percentage * max value)

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Don't use attr('data-min'), use data('min') in jQuery, HTML5 standard

Comment: My problem was passing 'String' instead of 'Number' to update slider values

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue with latest versions, too. The solution is easy: use **parseInt()** to pass dynamic values to sliders
Setter example for jquery ui slider:

```
    $("#mySlider").slider("option",{min: parseInt(value.min), max:parseInt(value.max),value: parseInt(value.active)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility - this error can come up if the min or max are missing for the slider.  If your startFiling or endFiling are not evaluating to a date, the slider code fails when trying to calculate the new handle position.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem using unmodified jQuery-UI.min.js. Using a custom script caused the error i.e jQuery-UI-custom.js

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI Slider plugin
min & max **options** accepts only number. So according to your requirement parse them to integer or float.

For details visit link-
http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/