# Slider cannot be dragged (Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined ) (jQuery UI Bootstrap + Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

When I create a simple slider `#slider` using Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.1, jQuery UI Bootstrap 1.8.16 and Backbone.js, I get the following error when I try to drag the slider handle (which does not follow the drag):

**JS Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

**JS**

```
renderSlider: function() {
    this.$el.find('#slider').slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {}
    });

},
```

I get the same error when I drag the slider handle if I don't pass any options to `.slider()`:

```
renderSlider: function() {
    this.$el.find('#slider').slider();
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: is jQuery being loaded? I'm trying to understand what all you're using... Twitter Bootstrap and Backbone.js and jQuery UI with the jQuery UI Bootstrap theme, and jQuery, right?

Comment: jQuery is loaded. Yes thats right

Comment: The slider now works if I use the latest version 1.8.23 of jQuery UI (not the custom build with Bootstrap theme currently at 1.8.16.

Comment: what line is causing that error? I don't see `addClass` in your code, so I'm assuming it's part of the slider, so maybe you aren't passing in a valid object? What is `this.$el`?

Comment: `this.$el` is the parent div that contains `<div id="slider"></div>`, so `this.$el.find('#slider')` will grab the slider div correctly

Comment: well, I guess it's irrelevant if you were able to get it working

Comment: I guess jQuery UI Bootstrap is not being actively maintained for quite a while, I will go with the original (and updated) jQuery UI and hope theres no collisions with Twitter Bootstrap

Comment: Did you also use the latest jQuery, version 1.8 or above? I think that it is incompatible with jQueryUI version below the 1.8.2+.

Comment: Yes I was using jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery UI Bootstrap 1.8.16. The incompatibility explains the errors. Thanks! Do you want to write that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery `1.8.x`. Theres a incompatibility issue with the version you've chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was not conflict between Bootstrap and jQuery UI.

I had same issue with slider. I removed bootstrap at all and it was still there. 
Only next helped:[jQuery UI slider - Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728079/jquery-ui-slider-cannot-call-method-addclass-of-undefined)

The latest version of jQuery UI.