# Bootstrap Datepicker with Angular2

Tags: jquery-plugins, angular, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I need to use [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) with Angular 2. So I created a component as follows

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/views/daily-reports.html'
})

export class DailyReportsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        $('#daily-reports').datetimepicker();
    }
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='daily-reports'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my index.html file I have all the files needed - js libraries and css files but I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined

When I try to use the same code without Angular I works correctly as usual. Is there a way to fix the problem or can anybody show me how to use this plugin in Angular2

Comment: Try to check this, looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728079/jquery-ui-slider-cannot-call-method-addclass-of-undefined

Answer (score 4):

You have to put that initialization in `ngAfterViewInit`, because the DOM is not rendered yet in `ngOnInit`, so the selector in your JQuery will not be found and thus return `undefined`.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('#daily-reports').datetimepicker();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `declare var jQuery:any;` then in `ngAfterViewInit` add:

```
jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).find('div[id="daily-reports"]').datetimepicker({format: 'LT'})
```